# How to clear listbox selection if I click empty field of listbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple Windows Form which contains a list box called `lstVersenyzok`. I have a `lstVersenyzok_SelectedIndexChanged` function. How can I clear the selection of the list box when I click the empty field of the list box? I tried, but it does not work if I check the condition `lstVersenyzok.SelectedIndex == -1`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MouseClick event and get the selected index by the `IndexFromPoint` method.
Check if the index is -1, then call the `lstVersenyzok.ClearSelected()` to clear the selection.

```
private void lstVersenyzok_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = this.lstVersenyzok.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
            if(index == -1)
            {
                lstVersenyzok.ClearSelected();
            }
        }
```

Hope this help !!

Comment: I tried it, but no reaction when I click empty field of list box, stay selected an item, and not remove selection.

Comment: I found the result, I writed the following code in the constructor of Form: `this.lstVersenyzok.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(lstVersenyzok_MouseClick);`. Thank you very much! Thank you for your help.